# setting installation path for python rpm

Tags: python, linux, packaging, fedora, rpm

Can I set the installation path (relative or absolute) for a python rpm's content?

Would I set this in the spec file?

Specifically I am trying to do this for Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you can build a new RPM, you can set it in the spec file.  How to do this depends on the package, but basically you get the package to install itself into the desired path inside the buildroot.

Probably the most common way to do that would be by passing `PREFIX` and `DESTDIR` to `make` in the `%install` target, e.g.:

```
%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
make -e install PREFIX=/home/user DESTDIR=%{buildroot}
```

If you want to do it without building a new RPM, you can install it using `rpm --relocate`, e.g.
`rpm --relocate /=/home/user -ivh <foo.rpm>`.

See the [rpm man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm) for details.

Comment: Uh, make install in /. That's a recipe for destroying your current Python installation...

Comment: Yeah, should have been `PREFIX=/home/user DESTDIR=%{buildroot}` or similar.

Comment: I want to set the install path inside of the rpm.  Two followups: (1) Can I create new directories e.g. /home/user/Activities/ (where Activities does not exist beforehand)? (2) Can I establish the install path to a user's home directory without knowing the user's name?  e.g. ~/Activities ?

Comment: (1) Why not just add a command `mkdir %{buildroot}/home/user/Activites` in the install section? (2) Try a `for user in $users` loop in a `%post` section.  Set `$users` based on `/home/*` or `/etc/passwd` or whatever.  See http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html for details.